# In terminal show on branch (PaymentStatus)

Tags: git, terminal

I was trying to connect my project on Git. When I was on terminal I go to my root folder and it shows (`PaymentStatus`) on branch. What is all about?

I am worried or I am safe to continue push my project on Git?

Comment: Do you have a git aware prompt (like [the one that comes with git completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh)) and a branch called `PaymentStatus`?

Comment: How do I find out about it? I am new with Git.

Comment: For the prompt, you can look at the output of `echo "$PS1"` (that's the prompt variable); for the branch, you can check `git branch -a | grep 'PaymentStatus'`.

Comment: It means that you have a branch called `PaymentStatus`. It is not quite clear from your context how your git repo is set up and what you did to see what you see; and even if it were, this kind of question might be better suited for [su].

Comment: When I run `git branch -a | grep 'PaymentStatus'` I got `* PaymentStatus` back. How can I remove it? What dose it mean anyway?

Comment: Thank you for your help I will post it.

Comment: The `* PaymentStatus` means that you have currently checked out the branch `PaymentStatus`. See also the output of `git status`.

Comment: Does not mean it will charge me or anything related to finance? I just worry cuz it does not shows with other folder.

Comment: It is really impossible to tell what is going on without knowing what commands you issued exactly, how you got your code in the first place etc. but `PaymentStatus` seems to be just a branch name. I also don't fully understand what you mean by "connect my project on Git".